# Duplicates in list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a values list in the below format. For every item in the list of lists, I am trying to find out whether it is present in any other sub-lists - if so, I would like to get a count of it.

```
[
    ['37772'],
    ['38119', '38120'],
    ['38103-2807', '38103-2897', '38103', '38104'],
    ['38138-3904', '38138'],
    ['37421'],
    ['37772'],
    ['37067'],
    ['37203'],
    ['38115'],
    ['38305'],
    ['37916'],
    ['37356'],
    ['38119']
]
```

Result:

```
37772 - 2
38119 - 2
38120 - 1
38103-2807 - 1
....
```

Any leads on how to achieve this using built-in functions?

Comment: Flatten all the lists, then use `collections.Counter()` to get all the counts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in modules [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
lst = [['37772'],
    ['38119', '38120'],
    ['38103-2807', '38103-2897', '38103', '38104'],
    ['38138-3904', '38138'],
    ['37421'],
    ['37772'],
    ['37067'],
    ['37203'],
    ['38115'],
    ['38305'],
    ['37916'],
    ['37356'],
    ['38119']]

from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
items = Counter(chain.from_iterable(lst))

for k, v in items.items():
     print(k, v) 


>>> 37772 2
>>> 38119 2
>>> 38120 1
>>> 38103-2807 1
>>> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li=[
    ['37772'],
    ['38119', '38120'],
    ['38103-2807', '38103-2897', '38103', '38104'],
    ['38138-3904', '38138'],
    ['37421'],
    ['37772'],
    ['37067'],
    ['37203'],
    ['38115'],
    ['38305'],
    ['37916'],
    ['37356'],
    ['38119']
]
for i in li:
    print(str(i)+str(li.count(i)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).